# Database: big amount of foreign keys

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

I have a mysql database about a gps system. It has about 70 tables.

One of the tables is called **vehicles** which has only one column containing the vehicles' ids and it is a primary key.

The rest of the tables contain a column called *vehicleId* which are all foreign keys.

I started to get worried if it is normal to have so many foreign keys pointing to only one table.

Actually this is my question: **Is it right to have 70 foreign keys pointing to only one primary key?**

P.S.  Some of the relations are one-to-one and some of them are one-to-many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, I am assuming you're using a Relational Database Management System of some kind, probably a SQL one.

If the relationships in the 'real world' are correct, i.e. each row in each of the 70 tables genuinely does hold data pertaining information for one vehicle then there is nothing wrong with doing this, per se, although one would usually expect to find more than a single Primary Key value in the 'vehicles' table.

From a purist database [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) perspective, one could argue that, where the one-to-one table mappings are concerned, the columns for each table could be moved to the 'vehicles' table. But it sounds as though this could be unwieldy for somebody trying to read the table if you have a vast amount of columns in the other one-to-one tables (assuming anybody would be interested in looking at the tables directly... it may well be all this is abstracted away by the front-end for your application anyway, or that you'd selectively examine the single table with lots of columns by using simple queries).

Then again, there are sometimes good performance reasons to selectively [Denormalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) parts of a database.

It all really depends on what you're trying to achieve. A good theoretical understanding of Normalization and Denormalization is probably a good place to start.

I generally take the approach that, for an RDBMS, I Normalize by default unless there are good reasons to do otherwise. And I would look to index properly and structure queries well before I would look to Denormalization as an option to improve performance.

I think, in your case, on the information provided, I'd want to move the columns off the one-to-one tables onto the 'Vehicles' table.

Comment: if i move that information in the vehicles table it will become over 50 columns.

Comment: Yes, and that is not a problem, in and of itself. If the vehicle genuinely has 50 properties that are one-to-one, then it's fine. Having said this, large numbers of columns can imply there are further one-to-many relationships which haven't been teased out yet. But it really depends on the situation.

Comment: some of the information is about money transactions AND sometimes i need to give read access to the table to other developers but my boss does not want them to see the details about the money so i think it is better idea to be in seperate tables:)

Comment: Ah! That changes things somewhat. There are other alternatives though. If you're using SQL Server (and I'm sure other RDBMS systems have similar features) you could still have everything in the one table, fully locked down so only Admins can see it, and then a read-only View built off this table containing only non-sensitive columns for the other developers to use.
If you keep different tables and want to query against them all, lots and lots of JOINs could impact performance. It is worth considering this if you're expecting a high transaction volume.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you cite doesn't necessarily mean you have a problem, but that doesn't mean this is a good design.

What's the alternative?  Duplicating that vehicle info in 70 tables?  That doesn't sound like a good idea to me.

I don't understand a vehicle table with a single column with just IDs.  Are there no meaningful attributes about vehicles that are needed?  VIN?  Make?  Model?  Year?  Garaging address?  I don't like the sound of this.  I'd question the rest of your design on this basis alone.

70 tables is *not* a large number.

What exactly is your problem?  Have you found that performance is an issue because of excessive JOINs?  Seven or fewer tables in a JOIN is the usual rule of thumb.

I'd worry about every table being coupled in this way.  It has the same issues that an object model that's too coupled.  You don't give enough details about your problem to say why you've arrived at this place, but I'd expect a better design to have clusters of tables that are naturally related.  Everyone talking to everyone feels like it could be one big table.  Not good at all.

Comment: It was more like a psychological issue because i started to worry that it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a good ER model that identifies the Entities, Relationships and Attributes that govern all the values to be stored in the database.  Create a table for each entity, with an identifying column that has a unique value for each instance of the entity.

Add foreign keys for relationships.  For many-to-many relationships, add tables to hold foreign key pairs (or triplets, etc.) For one-to-one relationships consider coalescing two entity tables into one.  If the relationship is optional,  you may want to keep the tables separate, but use a technique outlined in the following tag:  [shared-primary-key](/questions/tagged/shared-primary-key)

If this yields a databse schema like the one you've got, then it's probably good enough for most purposes.  If not, consider changing your schema.